# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I was using the old Place SDK which was working fine But it is going to be depreciated and I move to new place SDK. I got keep the crashing report from a few devices.

Crashes Report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.islamuna.ramadan/com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized.
```

SDK version:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

Even i initialize Place sample code:

```
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "mykey", Locale.US);

autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
            autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
            autocompleteFragment.setText(Global.getStoredStringValue(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.KEY_CITY)));

            autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    try {

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.

                }
            });
```

Layout XML

```
<fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_filled" />
```

Comment: I have same issue, any solution you got ?

Answer (score 37):

I was also facing the same issue but I resolved with this code.

```
 dependencies {
      implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
    }
```

First Step: Initialize the Places SDK In OnCreate Method or you can initialize it on your Application Class

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.api_key), Locale.US);
    }
```

Second Step:

```
 var fields=Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID,Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG)
    var intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).build(this)
     startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
```

And in Activity Result

```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val place =Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);

                lat = place.latLng?.latitude
                lng = place.latLng?.longitude
            }
            else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                var status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data)
                Log.i("address", status.getStatusMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

This is the Kotlin Example but you can convert in JAVA
Also, you can refer to this URL for Examples.
[Google Places SDK Example](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos)

Comment: This works for me but when I submit the app to google play, it says that map key has leaked to the public. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

You must initiase the google places library, below is the code:

Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.api_key));

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to on create:

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.api_key), Locale.US);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves my crash event - koin

com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzig.zzi
java.lang.IllegalStateException - Places must be initialized first.

Caused by org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException

```
single<GooglePlacesRepository> {
                    PlacesImpl(GooglePlacesSDKHandler.setupSDK(context))
                }


object GooglePlacesSDKHandler {

    fun setupSDK(context: Context?): PlacesClient {
        synchronized(Places.initialize(context, PLACES_API_KEY)) {
            return Places.createClient(context)
        }
    }
}
```