# Getting name of hospital closest to user without needing to use the actual Google map just the places api

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I need the app find the name of the closest hospital the user and display it in a TextView, the only examples I've seen of this is using the actual Google maps with the places API however I need to work just using the Places api to get the name of the hospital and return it. This the code I have so far (here I have tried the log the name):

```
private void findHospital() {
    List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME);
    FetchPlaceRequest fetchPlaceRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.builder("Hospital",placeFields).build();
    placesClient.fetchPlace(fetchPlaceRequest).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FetchPlaceResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FetchPlaceResponse fetchPlaceResponse) {
            Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
            Log.i("Hospital","Place found" + place.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

However the code throws an error, here's the logcat:

```
2020-04-10 16:15:32.877 24773-24773/com.example.blooddonorsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.blooddonorsystem, PID: 24773
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blooddonorsystem/com.example.blooddonorsystem.HospitalInNeedActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized first.
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzft.zzb(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.2.0:11)
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.2.0:36)
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.createClient(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@2.2.0:30)
    at com.example.blooddonorsystem.HospitalInNeedActivity.onCreate(HospitalInNeedActivity.java:76)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

EDIT:

fixed the problem with th permissions now I get this in the debug:

```
W/looddonorsyste: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/looddonorsyste: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=LE for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, ) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=LE for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, ) is already scheduled. Returning...
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020787/java-lang-illegalstateexception-places-must-be-initialized

Comment: thank you I fixed that I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to first initialize google places sdk.

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.api_key), Locale.US);
}
```